# array merge recursive with eloquent data laravel

Tags: php

hi guys i have trouble working with array merge on laravel, this my data :

```
<?php
use App\Http\Models\Tahuns;


public function merge(){
$tahun = Tahuns::pluck('tahun');
$value = [1,2,1];
$merge = array_merge_recursive($tahun,$value);
return $merge;
}
output :

0: 2010
1: 2011
2: 2012
​​​
```

i want get output something like this:

```
0: 
   0: 2010
   1: 1
1: 
   0: 2011
   1: 2
2: 
   0: 2012
   1: 1
```

can anyone with same experience help? thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using collection

for example

```
$value = [1,2,1];
$result = Tahuns::pluck('tahun')->map(function($year, $index) use (value) {
    return [
        $year,
        $value[$index]
    ];
})->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that keys on both arrays align, you could use map to achieve this.

```
$merge = collect($tahun)->map(function($item, $index) use ($values){
   return [ $item, $values[$index] ];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `for` loop to achive this

```php
<?php
use App\Http\Models\Tahuns;


public function merge(){
    $tahun = Tahuns::pluck('tahun');
    $values = [1, 2, 1];
    $merge = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($tahun); $i++) {

        $merge[] = [
            0 => $tahun[$i],
            1 => $values[$i],
        ];
    }
    return $merge;
}
```

output

```sh
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2010
            [1] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2011
            [1] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2012
            [1] => 1
        )

)
```